# Opening a URL from Excel (VBA) without browser opening

Tags: vba, excel, url, httprequest

We have a system that can create records simply by a URL being run with appropriate parameters. I would like to build this into Excel using VBA by executing my constructed URL in the background (no browser).

I found references on Stackoverflow to using `.post` with `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`, but in all occurrences that I have found of people using this they were looking to get a response from the website.

I have already tried this, but it didn't work (variables have already been declared).

```
Set httpSend = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
websiteURL = "https://www.somewebsite.com/?&staticVariable=xxxx" & URLEncode(variable1)
websiteArguments = "&anotherVariable=" & URLEncode(variable2)

httpSend.Open "POST", websiteURL, False
httpSend.Send (websiteArguments)
websiteResponse = httpSend.ResponseText
Set httpSend = Nothing
```

For the record, when I run the above, I get a run-time error about "**The HTTP redirect request failed**" at the `httpSend.Send (websiteArguments)` stage.

Is posting with WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 the best way to achieve the results I'm looking for. Is there another more efficient way to run a URL without opening a browser? Again to reiterate, I'm not looking for a response from the website, I just want to execute the URL.

Many thanks.

Comment: You may wanna use opening an IE window but make it not visible.

Comment: Try to make XHR also with `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`. Does the server use cookies?

Comment: @omegastripes I'm not sure whether the site uses cookies or not. Is the error I'm getting usually caused by that?

Can you advise why the use of XMLHTTP request? Is this more efficient?

Comment: @Joe all that ActiveX process redirects differently. `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` makes redirects by default, you can change that with `httpSend.Option(6) = False`, then send, and check redirect URL `httpSend.getResponseHeader("Location")`.